# What is the purpose of using VALUES or ALL in the first parameter of an iterator function?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I know that only CALCULATE can modify the filter context. However following are 2 example using VALUES and ALL.

Example 1:

Revenue =
SUMX(
Sales,
Sales[Order Quantity] * Sales[Unit Price]
)

```
Revenue Avg Order =
AVERAGEX(
    VALUES('Sales Order'[Sales Order]),
    [Revenue]
)
```

What is the purpose of VALUES in AVERAGEX function? Is this to add an additional filter context?

Example 2:

Product Quantity Rank =
RANKX(
ALL('Product'[Product]),
[Quantity]
)

What is the purpose of using ALL in an iterator function?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a table like this:

| ID | Sales Order | Order Quantity | UnitID | Unit Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 10 | 4 | 39.99 |
| 2 | 101 | 15 | 3 | 24.99 |
| 3 | 102 | 5 | 2 | 15.99 |
| 4 | 103 | 5 | 1 | 14.99 |
| 5 | 103 | 10 | 3 | 24.99 |

Since the `Sales Order` column has duplicates,

```
Revenue Avg Order = AVERAGEX ( VALUES ( Sales[Sales Order] ), [Revenue] )
```

gives a different result than

```
Revenue Avg ID = AVERAGEX ( Sales, [Revenue] )
```

since the first averages over the three `Sales Order` values whereas the second averages over the five `ID` rows.

[image: Table]

Using [DISTINCT](https://dax.guide/distinct/) instead of VALUES would work too.

---

Using ALL is instead of VALUES gives the same total but ignores the local filter context from the table visual:

```
Revenue Avg All  = AVERAGEX ( ALL ( Sales[Sales Order] ), [Revenue] )
```

[image: Table2]

In this context, ALL is acting as a table function that returns all of the distinct values of the column specified ignoring filter context.

Comment: But I have read that only CALCULATE can modify the filter context. I am confused on this point.

Comment: There’s an implicit CALCULATE when you call a measure, which results in a context transition from iterator row context to filter context.

Comment: ALL when used as a table functin does not remove filter context, it just ignores it.
Also, the RANKX is a peculiar function, we need to use ALL or ALLSELECTED otherwise we would build a lookup table for the ranking containing only the current item, therefore its result would always be 1

Comment: What is the difference between removing filter context and ignoring filter context please?